# Cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time; in combination with HashMap

Tags: rust

This is my code:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
struct Foo {
  pub map : HashMap<i32, String>
}
impl Foo {
  fn foo(&mut self, x: &String) -> i32 {
    // I'm planning to use/modify "x" here and also modify "self"
    42
  }
  fn bar(&mut self) -> i32 {
    let x = self.map.get_mut(&1).unwrap();
    self.foo(x)
  }
}
```

I'm getting:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:13:9
   |
12 |         let x = self.map.get_mut(&1).unwrap();
   |                 -------------------- first mutable borrow occurs here
13 |         self.foo(x)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^-^
   |         |        |
   |         |        first borrow later used here
   |         second mutable borrow occurs here
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modifying `self` and `x` here breaks memory safety (at least in the general situation, which is what Rust must deal with). Consider the following implementation of `foo` which is allowed by your signature (fixing `&String` to `&str`):

```
fn foo(&mut self, x: &str) -> i32 {
    self.map.clear();
    println!("{}", x);
    42
}
```

But you're calling this with `x` being a reference to something inside of `self.map`. So `x` could be destroyed by the time it's used. That's invalid, and Rust can't prove you won't do that, because you said you might. (Kevin Anderson provides a helpful comment below if you're coming from a GC language like C# where "reference" has a different meaning.)

How to fix this depends on what you're really trying to do, though one approach would be to clone the string so it cannot be destroyed:

```
fn bar(&mut self) -> i32 {
    let x = self.map.get(&1).unwrap().clone();  // <== now you have a copy
    self.foo(&x)
}
```

Note this got rid of the `get_mut()`. It's unclear what that was for. If you need an exclusive (`mut`) reference into the map, then you'll need to do that separately, and you can't do that directly while also holding an exclusive reference to `self` for the reasons above. Remember that `mut` means "exclusive access," not "mutable." A side effect of having exclusive access is that mutation is allowed.

If you really need something along these lines, you need to wrap your values (String) in `Arc` so that you can maintain reference counts and have shared ownership. But I would first try to redesign your algorithm to avoid this.

Comment: One additional point here for clarification for others: a reference in Rust is *somewhat* like a reference in C++ aka a non-resettable pointer that *does not* affect the lifetime of what it points to.  It is **not** like a "reference" in Python or C#, which is more like a reference-counted pointer, that will extend lifetimes as long as *something* is "referencing" it.  This is important IMO, and @Rob_Napier touches on this, but I feel it is important here.

Comment: Thanks @KevinAnderson. That is definitely an easy thing to misunderstand if you're coming from GC languages, or even ARC languages like Swift or ObjC. The comparison to C++ is apt.

Comment: @KevinAnderson What you wrote is correct, except for the _non-resettable_ part. Unlike C++ references, Rust ones are more like pointers in that they can be easily made to point to something else.